# Visual Studio 2013 loadtest: remote Controller cannot restart Agents and cannot run load test

Tags: visual-studio-2013, load-testing

I have succesfully installed a load test Controller and 3 agents on 4 different machines.  All of the services are running under the same domain account, and this account is in the Administrator's group on all four machines.  From each Agent machine I successfully registered with the controller using the Test Agent Configuration Tool.

In a Visual Studio 2013 load test project I selected the controller in the "Test Settings" dialog, and then from my load test I opened the "Manage Test Controller" dialog by clicking the wrench icon.  I see my selected controller, all 3 of my agents, and the correct database connection string that I used when setting up the controller.

If I click the "Restart Controller and Agents" button I get the error message "Rig failed to restart for controller 'Controller1'.  The following error was reported: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I click the same button again and get a slightly different error message: "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."

I can see that the controller is recieving the command, because this error is seen in the event viewer on the Controller machine, repeated for each agent:  (QTController.exe, PID 4984, Thread 15) AgentManager: Exception stopping agent service for agent 'Agent1' on machine 'Agent1.MyDomain.com': Cannot stop VSTTAgent service on computer 'Agent1.MyDomain.com'.

For each individual agent, I can select "restart" and it successfully restarts (I confirmed this by observing the Event Viewer on each agent machine).  Each agent shows as "Ready" in the status column

If I try to run the load test it shows "pending" for 60-90 seconds, then finally stops with the error message "Failed to queue test run 'MyName@MyMachineName 2015-10-28 11:44:23': A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond".

I turned on verbose logging for the controller service, and when I attempt to run the test I see that the service recieves the command.  The service tries repeatedly to connect to all 3 agents, this bit of code is printed for each agent in the log file repeatedly until my test errors out:

V, 3600, 26, 2015/10/28, 11:52:53.372, Controller1\QTController.exe, ControllerObject.RequireAgentServiceUser: Agent: Agent1 of environment [Default] trying to connect.
V, 3600, 26, 2015/10/28, 11:52:53.372, Controller1\QTController.exe, ControllerObject: AgentHello from Agent1
V, 3600, 26, 2015/10/28, 11:52:53.372, Controller1\QTController.exe, Verifying the connection integrity for following number of objects: 3

windows Firewall is turned off on all 5 machines (the controller, the 3 agents, and the machine with the Visual Studio loadtest project).

I've tried using the IP address of the controller instead of the host name (using the "bindto" appsetting in the controller configuration file) but get the same sad results.

I've tried rebooting and restarting all services, to no good effect.

Is there any way to debug or fix this issue?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: No @Igor-Mesaros.  I installed the controller software on a different machine, and it worked.  Still no idea what the problem was.